# Should I use an Object Oriented workflow for Vulkan core?

Tags: c++, vulkan

Despite beeing written in C++, the [famous vulkan tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Uniform_buffers/Descriptor_layout_and_buffer) stick everything in one class with functions using class members like global objects. I understand why such a tutorial don't enforce an object oriented workflow to focus on the API mechanics and let engine programmers setup their own workflow. But even CLion complains that an 600 lines file is too complex to analyse.

So my questions are, **is an object oriented layout suitable for the Vulkan boilerplate ?** Maybe once you have all the component setup this better to hide them in a file and only use higher level stuff like Meshes and Materials.
If so, **are there classic layouts that are more or less used across implementations ?**

So far I was able to put functions regarding Device (picking, logical device and swap chain creation, surface format and swap (present mode and extent) choice, queue families and memory finding, and other device related functions) in a separate file, but not in a class, validation layers have also their own file. Finally I made a Buffer class from which inherits Index, Vertex, Staging and Uniform buffers.

I found [this repo](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/tree/master/base) from what I understand, at the level where I am (uniform buffers) the workflow is split in Buffer, Debug, Device, FrameBuffer, Initialisers and SwapChain. **Is this a classic workflow or are there other ways ?**

Comment: Have you seen the [long list of C++ Vulkan wrapper libraries recommended by Khronos](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Khronosdotorg/blob/main/api/vulkan/resources.md#libraries)?

Comment: oh, that's interesting, thanks

Comment: This question risks being closed for being opinion-based. It's not a bad thing to ask by any means, but it might be more on-topic for one of the other stackexchange websites like https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com or something. That said; the general answer when using these types of graphics libraries is that OO does _not_ fit the design well. It's better to build the rendering system you want, and design abstractions around that in the end.

Comment: Also, vulkan-tutorial.com is not an 'official' vulkan tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vulkan has pro and cons versus OpenGL, it is not a replacement. Both libraries are in active development by Khronos, and will continue to do so.

Cons are obvious: Vulkan is much more wordy to do even basic things. From resizing a window requiring reconstructing all (most) your objects, to extremely limited number of active handles (thus requiring buffer packing), manual synchronization of multiple queues per device (with special code for single-queue devices), everything is very painstakingly done, with no safety nets. It is very easy to corrupt your buffers with too little synchronization, or completely kill performance with too much.

Pros now. Why use Vulkan over OpenGL? Well, you use Vulkan because you can construct and use exactly what you need. Don't need a depth buffer? Don't create one. Don't need a stencil buffer? Don't create one. Don't need to handle resizing windows? Don't pay the cost to handle them. Don't want runtime updateable buffers? Create static buffers and don't pay the cost to make updating them even possible.

Vulkan is strongly pushing you towards creating exactly the kind of engine you need, not something generic that handles everything. Pushing it to that extent, you'll just build OpenGL on top of Vulkan, and gain none of its performance benefits while inheriting all the difficulty in using it.

So that's your answer. OOP shouldn't really enter the equation here, you build a monolithic rendering engine that does exactly what you need it to do and nothing more.

Comment: "*Both libraries are in active development by Khronos, and will continue to do so.*" I see no evidence of this. Indeed, I see the opposite: OpenGL hasn't received an update in years, not even minor spec bug fixes. While Vulkan is being constantly updated and revised.

Comment: Well, the last OpenGL extension update was in [December 2020](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_texture_sRGB_RG8.txt). I guess the core OpenGL specification is stable so it's not updated much right now (last update was in 2019), whereas Vulkan being new it's getting a lot of basic functionality still (for example, cubic filtering).

Comment: So stable that [all of these bugs are basically being ignored.](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenGL-API/issues). Also, "[cubic filtering](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VK_IMG_filter_cubic.html)" is not "basic functionality." It's not part of any unextended version of OpenGL, and it's only an extension of OpenGL ES. And even then, it's a vendor-specific extension.